# How to resolve screen unlock login screen appearing after a long time?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro 15'' Retina running Mavericks.

When I lock the screen when stepping away and then attempt to reactivate it by either moving the mouse or entering some keys, the login screen doesn't appear immediately.

I am able to see the mouse pointer, repeatedly pressing any key results in the [action unavaiable] sound appearing but the login screen that will allow me to unlock the screen doesn't appear. It appears after a random amount of time after persistent attempts at unlocking the screen. How can I resolve this issue?